# Built the kernel with NFS support but not getting /dev/nfs

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs, root-filesystem

I'm trying to build kernel 3.13.9, fetched using `apt-get source`, and built in a clean `debootstrap` chroot (both host and chroot being installations of Ubuntu Trusty). My goal is to boot a diskless machine to a console over NFS.

I ran `make menuconfig` and enabled 64-bit kernel, disabled debugging, and made sure I was doing a 64-bit build. In addition, I went to file systems->network file systems, and enabled the following:

- Network File Systems
- NFS Client Support

The host has `nfs-kernel-server` installed, and an export set up for the directory that I would like to use as the root of the network-booted system.

PXE boot happens OK, kernel and initrd are loaded, but after a long pause, I'm dumped to a busybox prompt, due to a root filesystem being missing.

What could be the cause? (or, is more info needed?)

**Edit:** I'm already passing `nfsroot`:

```
LABEL linux
KERNEL vmlinuz-3.13.9
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-3.13.9 nfsroot=192.168.1.39:/nfsroot,rw ip=dhcp rw
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is with the compiling or that the flags don't seems to make any effect?

Comment: @Braiam I can compile just fine. I don't know how to check if NFS was actually put in, but I enabled it in the config, and didn't see any warnings regarding it. I'm not sure how the flags are being parsed, but /dev/nfs does not exist after the kernel comes up. I've checked in BusyBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt) states, `/dev/nfs` is not a real device but only a hint to the kernel to use NFS as `rootfs`.  You'll also have to tell the kernel where to find this root through the  `nfsroot` parameter or a properly set up DHCP daemon.  For the latter one to work you'll also have to either configure your kernel to auto-configure its network interfaces or have an `initramfs` which takes care of this.

Also, make sure to have NFS support built into your kernel binary and *not* as a module (or have an `initramfs`, which takes care of this).  Same goes for network drivers: you'll most probably want to have the driver for you ethernet NIC built into your kernel image, otherwise you'll have to load it from an `initramfs`.

In short, there are several possibilities:

1. Do as above link tells you: have `root=/dev/nfs` set, give the correct `nfsroot` parameter and tell your kernel your network configuration via the `ip` parameter (this would be the best way to make sure it's working at all, i.e. to rule out a misconfigured DHCP server).
2. Have `CONFIG_IP_PNP` and `CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP` enabled and set up a DHCP daemon to tell your client which IP address to use and where to find its NFS-root.
3. Build an `initramfs` which does the correct configuration and NFS-mounting.

**Edit:** I think if you're using an `initrd`/`initramfs` as your edit suggests, you'll have to do the NFS-mount in the `initrd` (resp. your `initrd` has to be aware of the fact that it has to do so).  Automounting through the kernel (as IP autoconfiguration, IIRC) only works if there's no `initrd`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm already passing nfsroot with the kernel append option. I'll edit the exact lines into my post shortly.

Comment: Could you indicate how to set up the initrd to perform the NFS mount?

Comment: Why don't you skip the `initrd`-part and let the kernel do autoconfiguration?  Configure your kernel to have everything needed for booting (network drivers, NFS support, …) built-in and enable `CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP`.  Would be much easier than fiddling with an `initrd`.

Comment: Since around 10 years the kernel doesn't boot nfs directly, but it mounts an initial ramdisk, which re-interprets the kernel command line and boots from where you want.

Comment: my pxe booting works fine from TFTP and mounting NFS as root. However I get a service failure message at boot time telling me `systemd-remount-fs.service` failed. Most likely this is because in `fstab` has `/dev/nfs` listed as root device, which does in fact not exist. How do I fix the issue? Do I just alter fstab to `ip:/nfs/path / nfs defaults,rw,relatime 0 0`?

Answer (score 0):

FalcoGer, I was asking myself the exact same question.  Since we are already passing root=/dev/nfs as a parameter in the bootloader I tried to comment this line and systemd-remount-fs stopped complaining!  Wondering now if this is really required

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).