# archlinux efi netboot kernel "ip" does not work?; systemd "Failed to start Switch Root."

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, systemd, nfs, netboot

I am attempting to set up a diskless [node/workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskless_node)/[system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Diskless_system), using the instructions provided in the guide [Diskless system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Diskless_system) for [archlinux](https://www.archlinux.org) (4.13.12-1-ARCH).

## the problem

The client successfully connects to TFTP ([atftp](http://github.com/seveas/atftp)), transfers all files and presents the GRUB selection menu (relevant excerpt from `grub.cfg`):

```
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzip
insmod ext3
insmod net
insmod tftp
insmod efinet

set root=(tftp,192.168.0.101)
set prefix=(tftp,192.168.0.101)/netboot/grub

linux /netboot/vmlinuz-linux add_efi_memmap root=/dev/nfs rootfstype=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.101:/srv/[CLIENT OS] nfsrootdebug rw ip=dhcp
initrd /netboot/initramfs-linux.img
```

I have tried various assignments of `ip` (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt)

```
 ip=:::::efinet0:dhcp
 ip=:::::eno1s0:dhcp
 ip=:::::eth0:dhcp
 ip=[CLIENT IP]:[SERVER IP]:[GATEWAY IP]:[NETMASK]:[HOSTNAME]:[DEVICE]:dhcp
```

While both `linux` and `initrd` are loaded, continuing results in

```
[FAILED] "Failed to start Switch Root."
See 'systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service' for details.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reobot, "systemctl default or ^D to enter into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

## troubleshooting

### removing add_efi_mmap

Instead of `Failed to start Switch Root.`, the kernel panics:

```
[    1.114386] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,255)
[    1.114458] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.13.12-1-ARCH #1 
[    1.114509] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. UX51V2A/UX51VZA, BIOS UX51VZA.204 12/03/2012
[    1.114573] Call Trace:
[    1.114604]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[    1.114637]  panic+0xe4/0x23d
[    1.114667]  mount_block_root+0x1f4/0x2ab
[    1.114703]  ? set_debug_rodata+0x17/0x17
[    1.114737]  mount_root+0x6a/0x6d
[    1.114767]  prepare_namespace+0x134/0x16c
[    1.114802]  kernel_init_freeable+0x1ec/0x205
[    1.114840]  ? rest_init+0xe0/0xe0
[    1.114872]  kernel_init+0xc/0xfc
[    1.114904]  ret_from_fork+0x25/0x30
[    1.114957] Kernel Offset: 0x3000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    1.115040] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,255)
```

### [systemd debugging](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/)

I cannot access the journalctl. Either the keyboard is not detected or the system freezes because I can neither press `Enter` nor `^D` to continue.

Attempting to directly boot into emergency mode by adding `systemd.unit=emergency.target` or `emergency` to the kernel CLI does not seem to work.

+(UPDATE 2) The `mkinitcpio` argument `break=premount` does not change the `systemd` startup.

### network

Using Wireshark, there is no network activity after the initial PXE boot, that is, when `linux` and `initrd` are loaded, there is no more communication between the client and server.

```
SERVER IP: 192.168.2.101/24
CLIENT IP: 192.168.2.102/24
```

#### GRUB

The GRUB net_* [commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Networking-commands.html#Networking-commands) and [environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html) seem to indicate that everything is in order; tftp works.

```
net_ls_cards  efinet0 [CLIENT NETWORK DEVICE MAC]
net_ls_addr   efinet0 [CLIENT NETWORK DEVICE MAC] 192.168.2.102
net_ls_routes efinet0:local 192.168.2.0/24 efinet0
              efinet0:default 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.2.101

echo $net_default_ip               192.168.2.102
echo $net_default_mac              [CLIENT NETWORK DEVICE MAC]
echo $net_default_server           192.168.2.101
echo $net_efinet0_ip               192.168.2.102
echo $net_efinet0_mac              [CLIENT NETWORK DEVICE MAC]
echo $net_efinet0_hostname         (empty)
echo $net_efinet0_domain           (empty)
echo $net_efinet0_dhcp_server_name (empty
echo $net_efinet0_next_server      192.168.0.101
echo $net_efinet0_root_path        102.168.0.101:/srv/[CLIENT OS]
echo $net_efinet0_extensionpath    (empty)
```

#### Kernel support for `nfsroot` and `ip`

Given that there is no network activity, I presume that the `ip` or `nfsroot` are not being executed.

In fact, the problem I am having is described in the question [Built the kernel with NFS support but not getting /dev/nfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140176/built-the-kernel-with-nfs-support-but-not-getting-dev-nfs).

The answer to that question states (Andreas Wiese Jul 1 '14 at 14:58)

> ... make sure to have NFS support built into your kernel binary and not as a module (or have an `initramfs`, which takes care of this). Same goes for network drivers: you'll most probably want to have the driver for you ethernet NIC built into your kernel image, otherwise you'll have to load it from an `initramfs`.
>   
>   In short, there are several possibilities:
>     1. Do as above link tells you: have `root=/dev/nfs` set, give the correct `nfsroot` parameter and tell your kernel your network configuration via the `ip` parameter (this would be the best way to make sure it's working at all, i.e. to rule out a misconfigured DHCP server).
>     2. Have `CONFIG_IP_PNP` and `CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP` enabled and set up a DHCP daemon to tell your client which IP address to use and where to find its NFS-root.
>     3. Build an initramfs which does the correct configuration and NFS-mounting.

Investigating the archlinux kernel

```
zgrep CONFIG_NFS_FS= /proc/config.gz -> CONFIG_NFS_FS=m
zgrep DHCP /proc/config.gz           -> (nothing)
zgrep _IP_PNP_ /proc/config.gz       -> CONFIG_IP_PNP is not set
```

indicates that archlinux does not have support for the `ip` compiled with the kernel.

In comment from a bug report (2006) [FS#5056 - Default kernel has NFS root mouting disabled](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/5056?opened=243&status%5B0%5D=)

> mkinitcpio supports netbooting already without changing the kernel

Which can be compared to the comment to the accepted answer in the referred question.

> Since around 10 years the kernel doesn't boot nfs directly, but it mounts an initial ramdisk, which re-interprets the kernel command line and boots from where you want. – peterh Jun 17 '16 at 13:54

#### mkinitcpio

From the `lsinitcpio -a`

```
...
Created with mkinitcpio 24
Kernel: 4.13.12-1-ARCH
Size: 55,63 MiB
Compressed with: gzip
  ...

Included modules:
... nfs ... nfsv3 nfsv4 [explicit] ...

Included binaries:
... ipconfig ... mount.nsf4 ... nfsmount ...  

Early hook run order:
udev

Hook run order:
udev net net_nsf4 nbd

Cleanup hook order:
udev
```

#### mkinitcpio support for network device (update #1)

Although the drivers for the network card should be loaded, I wanted to make sure after reading [[SOLVED] Diskless - ipconfig: no devices to configure](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169335).

> put network module drive in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf.

```
MODULES=(atl1c nbd nfsv4)
```

Neither explicitly declaring the module nor building the entire `initramfs.img` on the client made no change.

> Don't use autodetect if the image should run on different machines. autodetect removes all drivers which are not necessary for booting on the currently running system.

Removing `autodetect` from hooks resulted in an interesting outcome; the earlier observed kernel panic when removing `add_efi_mmap` occurred. Removing `add_efi_mmap` when loading the no-`autodetect` `initramfs` had no further effect.

#### mkinitcpio support for `nfs`

Archlinux may or may not have support for nsf4.

- [mkinitcpio Runtime customization Using net](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mkinitcpio#Using_net)
- [FS#28287 - [mkinitpio-nfs-utils] NFS4 Support](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/28287)

As far as I can tell, this is a secondary issue; the network must work before an attempt to mount nfs can be made.

#### mkinitcpio support for `ip`

I have just found out that

- [mkinitcpio-nfs-utils (0.3-5)](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/mkinitcpio-nfs-utils/) includes a "ipconfig",
- there is a [mkinitcpio-netconf 0.0.4-2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mkinitcpio-netconf/).

## additional information

This may or may not be relevant.

The reason for using "UEFI PXE boot" instead of "BIOS PXE boot" is because GRUB i386-pc fails to load the grub.cfg. The computer either restarts, freezes on "Welcome to GRUB!" and may clutter the screen with colorized pixels; the outcome seems random. The Wireshark logs reveal that `tftp` sometimes loads all grub modules, sometimes not. The last log entry is often the client asking for the server network device; `ARP 60 Who has [SERVER IP]? Tell [CLIENT IP]?`

Comment: Similar problem description but with the network functioning [NFS root filesystem doesn't mount at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204872/nfs-root-filesystem-doesnt-mount-at-boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the instructions in the Arch Linux wiki for [diskless systems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Diskless_system&oldid=489317)

For the client installation

> create a full Arch Linux installation in a subdirectory on the server.

then

> Edit $root/etc/mkinitcpio.conf and add nfsv4 to MODULES, net_nfs4 to HOOKS, and /usr/bin/mount.nfs4 to BINARIES

As I understood it, simply add `net_nfs4` to the default hooks in `mkinitcpio.conf`. Searching for an answer, I cannot recall anything about necessary hooks, rather, I ended up instead adding the `net` hook in the confusion of reading other guides that were presumingly intended for nfs3.

Finally I came across [We deal with loading of ArchLinux on network](http://developers-club.com/posts/253573/) [Roshalsky 22 марта 2015 в 16:14](https://habrahabr.ru/post/253573/).

The article has a section named *We prepare initramfs* that is in the beginning familiar to the Arch Linux wiki,

```
# sed s/nfsmount/mount.nfs4/ "$root/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/net" > "$root/etc/initcpio/hooks/net_nfs4"
# cp $root/usr/lib/initcpio/install/net $root/etc/initcpio/install/net_nfs4
```

but it differs on some crucial points.

Firstly, edit the net_nfs4 file, which in Arch Linux is

```
nano $root/usr/lib/initcpio/install/net_nfs4

build() {
    add_checked_modules '/drivers/net/'
    add_module nfsv4?

    add_binary "/usr/lib/initcpio/ipconfig" "/bin/ipconfig"

    # Not sure if it is an Arch Linux specific, but nfsmount is correct;
    # mount.nsf4 causes mkinitcpio during build to throw an error like "file not found".
    # add_binary "/usr/bin/mount.nfs4" "/bin/mount.nfs4"
    add_binary "/usr/bin/nfsmount" "/bin/mount.nfs4"

    add_runscript
}
```

Secondly,

> We add the processor to initramfs by correction of line in the mkinitcpio.conf file:

```
nano $root/etc/mkinitcpio.conf

HOOKS="base udev net_nfs4"
```

## UPDATE +(20171210)

Trying to solve [another problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409768/archlinux-netboot-diskless-node-system-systemd-on-nfs-v4-fails-rpc-idmapd/410131#410131) I noticed in the `/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/net_nfs4` defined function `nfs_mount_handler` the following line:

```
mount.nfs4 ${nfs_option:+-o ${nfs_option}} "${nfs_server}:${nfs_path}" "$1"
```

According to the `man mount.nfs4`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   mount.nfs remotetarget dir [-rvVwfnsh ] [-o options]

DESCRIPTION
   ...
   remotetarget is a server share usually in the form of servername:/path/to/share.  dir is the directory on which the file system is to be mounted.
   ...
```

therefore, I have changed that line to:

```
mount.nfs4 "${nfs_server}:${nfs_path}" "$1" ${nfs_option:+-o ${nfs_option}}
```